# Copying a text file into a calculation sheet with a script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, file-copy, libreoffice, excel

I would like to create a script that can write up from a text file a LibreOfficeCalc or equivalent table with the same columns than the following those from the following lines from a text file :

```
[1] 119.0(0.0)  73.0(0.0)
[2] 40.0(0.0)   17.0(0.0)
[3] 574.0(0.0)  469.0(0.0)
[4] 46.0(0.0)   47.0(0.0)
[5] 1.0(0.0)    2.0(0.0)
[6] 24001.0(0.0)    24618.0(0.0)
[7] 61.0(0.0)   91.0(0.0)
[8] 1.0(0.0)    1.0(0.0)
[9] 3910.0(0.0) 3491.0(0.0)
[10] 379.0(0.0) 381.0(0.0)
[11] 458.0(0.0) 445.0(0.0)
[12] 46.0(0.0)  48.0(0.0)
[13] 5598.0(0.0)    5619.0(0.0)
[14] 1653.0(0.0)    1644.0(0.0)
[15] 218.0(0.0) 223.0(0.0)
[16] 2.0(0.0)   2.0(0.0)
[17] 1.0(0.0)   1.0(0.0)
[18] 52.0(0.0)  50.0(0.0)
[19] 52.0(0.0)  55.0(0.0)
[20] 71.0(0.0)  72.0(0.0)
[21] 21.0(0.0)  21.0(0.0)
[22] 2193.0(0.0)    2151.0(0.0)
[23] 424.0(0.0) 433.0(0.0)
[24] 382.0(0.0) 369.0(0.0)
[25] 50.0(0.0)  49.0(0.0)
[26] 237.0(0.0) 233.0(0.0)
[27] 55.0(0.0)  57.0(0.0)
[28] 10539.0(0.0)   11519.0(0.0)
[29] 428.0(0.0) 422.0(0.0)
[30] 872.0(0.0) 897.0(0.0)
[31] 2219.0(0.0)    2198.0(0.0)
[32] 919.0(0.0) 946.0(0.0)
[33] 6.0(0.0)   5.0(0.0)
[34] 12.0(0.0)  12.0(0.0)
[35] 64.0(0.0)  60.0(0.0)
[36] 37.0(0.0)  34.0(0.0)
[37] 26.0(0.0)  27.0(0.0)
[38] 26.0(0.0)  29.0(0.0)
[39] 6.0(0.0)   6.0(0.0)
[40] 8.0(0.0)   7.0(0.0)
[41] 3371.0(0.0)    3366.0(0.0)
[42] 139.0(0.0) 140.0(0.0)
[43] 149.0(0.0) 147.0(0.0)
[44] 147.0(0.0) 151.0(0.0)
[45] 1047.0(0.0)    1027.0(0.0)
[46] 88.0(0.0)  93.0(0.0)
[47] 28.0(0.0)  27.0(0.0)
[48] 2904.0(0.0)    2945.0(0.0)
[49] 122.0(0.0) 114.0(0.0)
[50] 422.0(0.0) 413.0(0.0)
```

I knwo how to write content a new file

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "some file content" > /path/to/outputfile
```

But how to actually read lines and automatize writing in different columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood your question properly,

If your objective is to read the text file with any spreadsheet software like LibreOffice, you can change the default delimiter from ***','*** to ***whitespace*** and read them as columns.

**Solution Update:**

To create a *.csv* out of a text file separated by whitespaces, use
`sed -e 's/ \{1,\}/,/g' values.txt > values.csv`

Comment: Actually it is to copy these values line by line to three columns in a speadsheet in any spreadsheet software like LibreOffice.

Comment: `sed -e 's/ \{1,\}/,/g' values.txt > values.csv`, this will create what you expected irrespective of the number of columns as long as they are separated by whitespace (single or multiple).

Comment: Okay, I just accepted and what about if I want to suppress the `(0.0)` at the same time ? Oh, I see, it is : `sed -e 's/(0.0)/ /g;s/  */ /g' values.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Yes, This would solve it.  But for the space, I would recommend using `sed -e 's/(0.0)//g; s/ \{1,\}/,/g' values.txt > values.csv`.  Using `s/ */ /g` would match zero spaces as well.